# entity framework with c#, retrieving saved objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm new to EF, and after looking at tutorials, it seems like I can save the data just fine, but don't know the code to retrieve it. My class looks like

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int index { get; set; }
    public string name;
    public List<string> type;
    public List<string> def;
    public HashSet<string> syns;
    public HashSet<string> generator_list = new HashSet<string>();
    public List<Point> related_items2 = new List<Point>();
}
```

And the EF code looks like

```
    using (var ctx = new Context())
    {
        foreach (Item block in items)
        {
            ctx.items_db.Add(block);
        }
        ctx.SaveChanges();

        var test = from b in ctx.items_db
                    orderby b.index
                    select b;
    }
```

I have 9000 Item instances, and I'd just like to save them in a database and then retrieve them into a `List<Item>` with all the instances. But I don't think I'm doing it right with  `var test`, because that doesn't appear to be a `List<Item>` and I can't seem to access it outside of the `using` statement block.

The only reason I'm doing this is because the ONLY thing I want is to save the related_items2 property (so I don't have to regenerate it upon every restart) because there are 9000 elements in it and it takes a while (20 min) to generate 9000 instances. I tried using protobuff but that still takes up 200mb and I get errors when I try to read the data back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use `.ToList()` to change data to list of Items
if you not using `.ToList` your test variable is `IQueryable` and not list of data
that out side of using not worked

```
var test=new List<Item>();
using (var ctx = new Context())
{
    foreach (Item block in items)
    {
        ctx.items_db.Add(block);
    }
    ctx.SaveChanges();

    test = (from b in ctx.items_db
                orderby b.index
                select b).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work! But I think I'm still doing something wrong, because I'm expecting a list of 9000 elements, but I'm getting 18000 or so, and all the fields are blank except for the index? I looked up deleting the table so I could start over and troubleshoot but that requires the table name, but I don't know what that is in my case?

Comment: @user3408097 I think that your table not empty from start or you run this code twice that cause to get list of 18000 elements

Comment: Do you know how I can delete table? This code gives me an error `ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [items_db]");`

Comment: @user3408097 your code must work for drop table, what is the error?

Comment: The error is " Cannot find the object items_db because it does not exist or you do not have permission."